# Why does Vermont keep picking the party for governor with fewer votes since 2006/2014?

Tags: united-states

```
Year, VT voting for winning party nationally, party candidate elected VT governor
2006, No, R
2008, No, R
2010, No, D
2012, Yes, D
2014, No, D
2016, No, R
2018, No, R
2020, No, R
```

Why does Vermont have such a bad track record of picking the party that is more popular at the top of the ticket nationally? The midterms, are of course House elections.

I feel this is notable because Vermont is an "elastic" state, so it would make sense for it to move with the nation. But 2008 2016 and 2018 do not make sense to me. 2018 in particular doesn't make sense because there was a 6.5 pp swing towards the Democrats and the Dem did worse despite Sanders (not exactly a Democrat but a leftist nevertheless) being on the ballot.

Comment: Could you add what the party the governor is for those years? Also why does the governor following the national popular party matter?

Comment: That would not make much sense, but I'll do it anyway.

Comment: Because winning the control of the house, senate and white house doesn't mean that it is the most popular party nationally. At best you can look at total number of votes for each party and determining which one received the most amount of votes.

Comment: Exactly just like 2016. Clinton got 3M more votes which is why 2016 is no. And the popular party matters because of the elasticity and my curiosity.

Comment: Also if you look at the data the Lieutenant Governor from 2011-2016 was Phil Scott who took over office in 2017 (after the 2016 election)  so while the party may have switched he was working for a Democrat governor and just moved up in position. If you look at it the party in office has been switching each time a new Governor takes office since 1963 when Phillip H. Hoff took office.

Comment: By the way I am a staunch Democrat who struggles to understand why people claiming to be liberal are doing this to themselves. I always vote Democrat, except for 2016 when I didn't vote at all. (The US did vote Dem for president that year with plurality, but that doesn't matter.)

Comment: My next question will be *Why does straight ticket voting seem unevenly distributed geographically across the US?* -- I think it might have to do with race.

Comment: The problem is that people often vote straight ticket based on party rather than the qualifications of the candidate. If people actually votes on that than it should help improve the quality of them overall.

Comment: Some people vote split ticket not for a check on power, but because they feel their party has a bad candidate and they really hate the candidate. That could have contributed to Clinton's popular vote victory. GOP won House by 1 percentage point that year. I have heard about Republicans who are voting for their Republican senator and house people but are voting for Biden because they feel Trump is a bad person.

Comment: Is the question why Vermont voters didn't follow the votes of the country as a whole or why the results of Vermont's elections for state-level officials don't match the results of the ones for federal-level officials?

Comment: Why the state level votes don't match the country as a whole.

Comment: Elastic state per 538 is one that tends to move with the rest of the country. I am adding this because I know what Numberfile is saying

Comment: What is the source of this information?

Answer (score 5):

> Why does Vermont have such a bad track record of picking the party that is more popular at the top of the ticket nationally?

What a bizarre idea.  State elections do not have to match any national trend or everyone would elect the same party controlling every State.  The purpose of a State election is to choose a candidate who is most popular with *only* the people of that State (or who can vote in that election).

That candidate does not even have to be a member of any party.  Wikipedia has a list of [governors who were independents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_third_party_and_independent_United_States_state_governors).

Deciding who should run your State is not at all the same as who should run the US.  Different jobs with different priorities.  National priorities do not necessarily match State ones.  You want a governor who will fight for *your* state, not one who will automatically back the national leader.  Maybe the question should be why this doesn't happen more often, not why Vermont does it.

Comment: They are actually starting to and are doing so more and more. And by they I mean state level elections in most states. New England is a big exception though there is a trend in that direction as well but it's not 100% clear. example: Senate and President 2016. For governor, median split ticket hit new low in 2018.

Comment: @NumberFile I appreciate the accepted answer vote, however I am bound to point out, in all fairness, that SE users are encouraged to wait 24 hours or so to accept an answer as a better one may turn up.

Comment: @NumberFile no, that's really mistaken.  If you look at a national map, you'll see very clear geographic division in the support for the leading two parties.  New England is an example, but far from the only one; really a bit more than half of the total population is in areas leaning towards the Democratic party, but in recent years a hair more than half of the individual states have at state level leaned Republican.  Hence you get things like the popular vote and House going one way, but the by-state Senate and Electoral College going the other.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with race, party ID, and tradition.

More so than other parts of New England, Vermont is overwhelmingly white and more irreligious. Those two things together make the state more elastic and willing to vote for members of the other party. It may fly in the face of the concept of elasticity on the surface, but the principle of being able to vote for the other party is there. Nonwhite voters, on the other hand, are overwhelmingly Democratic, and those who directly identify as such  do not split their tickets. However. That is why mostly African-American districts are inelastic, as well as many urban districts. (The same thing also happens in whiter urban districts to a lesser degree, but that's a topic for another time.)

Vermont has a high concentration of independents. It even has an independent senator, who broke Duverger's law in the 1990s. That adds to the elasticity. That allows them to not only outperform the national party but to break above 50%. There is also a myth (sort of) of moderate Republicans which Susan Collins sort of debunks.

As someone else said, VT switched parties a lot for governors. That adds to the elasticity. They are possibly believers in the false idea that Democrats and Republicans are the same.  *This party switching happens at the right times to inversely align and that is the ultimate reason.*